# Issue connecting to S3 from AWS Lambda(Ruby2.5)

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, ruby-2.5

I am trying to connect to AWS S3 bucket from AWS lambda.

I am using aws-sdk-s3 gem.

My code working fine on local machine. I was able to upload files to S3.
But the same code giving timeout on lambda.

```
def client
  Aws::S3::Client.new({
    region: 'ap-south-1',
    credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(
      '',
      ''
    )
  })
end

def resource
  Aws::S3::Resource.new(client: client)
end

def bucket
  resource.bucket(bucket_name)
end
```

Should I do something more to make this code run on lambda?

Comment: Timeouts are usually due to network misconfiguration. Is your Lambda function running in a VPC?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was gem `aws-sdk-s3` gem wasn't installed on Lambda.
Check it out: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/ruby-package.html

Comment: I have bundled the required gems. That was not the issue.